# JavaScript/CoffeScript returns "[object Object]" insted of right value

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, return-value

I wrote a nodejs Server.

```
app.get("/admin", function (req, res) {
    var connection, value;
    connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "******",
        user: "*****",
        password: "****",
        database: "YaAMP",
        insecureAuth: true
    });
    value = mySQLgetValue("SELECT property, value FROM config WHERE property = 'primeMult'", connection);
    console.log("Return Value" + value); //returns "[object Object]"
    connection.end();
    return res.render("admin", {
        title: "YaAMP"
    });
});
```

And a `mySQLgetValue` Function to get the a value from the MySQL Database, which should return a specific value from the DB.

```
mySQLgetValue = function (queryString, connection) {
    var value;
    value = 0;
    return connection.query(queryString, function (err, rows, fields) {
        console.log("Value " + rows[0].value); //Returns correct value
        return value += rows[0].value;
    });
};
```

The `console.log` in the `mySQLgetValue` function returns the correct value from the DB. But the function call returns an `Object` and `console.log` prints "[object Object]".

What is wrong?

Comment: Is `mySQLgetValue` really synchronous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `console.log()` is variadic, so use a comma instead of `+`.

```
console.log("Return Value", value);
```

---

The `+` does string concatenation, which calls the `.toString()` on the object, which is why you were getting `[object Object]`.

---

You can't get the `return` value from the callback that you're passing to `connection.query`, because you're not the one invoking that function.

Instead, define another parameter to your function to receive a callback function that is invoked inside the callback passed to `connection.query`. This will replace the `return` statement.

```
app.get("/admin", function (req, res) {
    var connection, value;
    connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "******",
        user: "*****",
        password: "****",
        database: "YaAMP",
        insecureAuth: true
    });

    var q = "SELECT property, value FROM config WHERE property = 'primeMult'";

     // Pass a callback-----------------v
    mySQLgetValue(q, connection, function(val) { console.log(val); });

    connection.end();

    return res.render("admin", {
        title: "YaAMP"
    });
});

        // callback parameter ------------------------v
mySQLgetValue = function (queryString, connection, callback) {
    var value;
    value = 0;
    return connection.query(queryString, function (err, rows, fields) {
        console.log("Value " + rows[0].value);

         // Invoke your callback
        callback(value += rows[0].value);
    });
};
```

Comment: now the console.log outupt is this:
http://pastebin.com/y0gK1900

Comment: @user2330362: It's logging the object you received. If the result is not what you expected, check with the API documentation.

Comment: but within my function I get the right value, only after returning it I get this object which I don't expect.

Comment: @user2330362: Oh, I see. You can't return anything from the callback. That inner `return value += rows[0].value` is being returned to the inner code that is invoking the callback. What you need to do is add another parameter to your function, and pass a function to that parameter, and then invoke the function inside the current callback, passing it the value. I'll update to demonstrate.